# Fill Incomplete Holes in 3D Image of Corals

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, morphological-operations

I'm trying to analyse a series of CT scans of coral samples, but am fairly new to this sort of image processing.

The problem I've hit is that a lot of the coral is hollow (in the images), and even worse, a lot is hollow but open sided (ie incomplete holes). For the complete circles I can use a Fill Holes process, which tends to work well.

But, since most of the coral holes are only semicircles the software cannot detect it's true shape. Is there something that might interpolate the missing coral and then fill the internal structure.

[image: Some complete and some incomplete holes]

As seen in this image, some of the coral structure creates a complete circle (eg bottom right), but others are just semicircular shapes, or even hollow tubes (mid-right, top-right, all over the place...).

This may be further confused by the fact that in reality it is trying to fill a volume (as opposed to an area) because the images stack up into a 3d structure.

I am trying to use ImageJ, but am willing to try other tools if there is a way around this.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires the hollows to be filled?

Comment: Ah yes. I am trying to create a skeleton that represents the coral branches. Unfortunately the skeletonisation processes that are available in ImageJ regard every minor shape change as a new skeleton, and therefore create a huge skeleton of millions of bones.
I am also trying to measure the volume of the coral, and the surface area. Incomplete circles appear to disrupt these measurements.